# Firebase send group message to more than 20 members

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

### Problem

I am developing an android application which sends notification to all user with in the same city. let say we have to send 1000 notification when user click request button. how I can acheive this using firebase. right now i am using group message to send the notification but it just send it to 20 member.

Comment: Why not just use [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) for this? Having topics for each city.

Comment: yes, you are possibly right.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
You can divide set of tokens as subset 1000 tokens each.

**Step 2**
Your function send_1000_notification can be called for each 1000 tokens set.

**Step 3**
Determine the total number of unique tokens you have in your firebase database

**Step 4** 
Afterwards send to 1000 at once, then move onto the next set of 1000 and so on.

Comment: how i can define schema in firebase database like this as your given answer 
Tokens : [
 Tokens_A : [ "1", "2" , ... "1000"],
 Tokens_B : [ "1", "2" , ... "1000"],
 Tokens_C : [ "1", "2" , ... "1000"],
 .
 .
 .
 Tokens_N : [ "1", "2" , ... "1000"]
]